# visual studio sending request to symweb during load test?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, load-testing

I'm running a load test against my service and I choose a test already in my solution. But the test needs some nuget packages such as Newsonsoft.Json and so on.
When the load test is run, the visual studio tries to find the symbol file(.pdb file) of the nuget packages. Without surprise, the request failed. And the code parts requiring those packages are passed by and the test failed.

[image]

I wonder if there's any way to prevent the visual studio to load the symbol file? Thank you so much

Comment: There are two ways of executing the test. Are you running it or debugging it?